# How I can skip installing optional dependencies by 'npm ci'?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-ci

How I can skip installing optional dependencies from `package-lock.json` by `npm ci`?

Comment: Please solutions that are for `npm ci` and not `npm install`

Comment: Hi, sorry for bothering you, but have you finally found any solution? Except these "remove lock file, lol" of course :)

Answer (score 15):

You can use npm ci --no-optional .
If npm still installs the optional package. Then try after removing package.lock.json and run the command again.

Comment: I need to use `npm ci` instead `npm install`, and shouldn't remove `package-lock.json`. And yes, I know about `npm install --no-optional`, but that's not really my case

Answer (score 8):

There was an error in NPM's implementation of `npm ci --no-optional`. It has been fixed in versions > 6.13.3 - maybe earlier versions as well, but I can only vouch for 6.13.4 and up.

Comment: It's never too late <3 Thank you!

Comment: confirmed. CI was using npm 6.11.3 and --no-optional was not being respected. Upgraded to 6.13.4 and now it is. cheers all

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. Is there a documentation anywhere that lists this flag for npm ci? On my machine I am having troubles with fsevents being installed on windows with npm ci (which does not work as it is Mac-OS specific) but not with npm i. Thus npm ci is not usable

Comment: @rominator007 Make shure you deleted package-lock.json first. I don't know any docs for that. I assume every `npm install` options  work with `npm ci`.

Comment: @MaximeGélinas The whole point of using npm ci is to load the packages as of what is written to package-lock.json. At least that is documented https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci So sorry that is not a solution

Comment: @rominator007 Make sure package is marked as optional in package-lock.json.

Comment: I am on npm 6.14.11, optional deps are marked as `"optional": true` in the package-lock.json but it still install them when running `npm ci --no-optional`.
I found a quite recent threads on npm forum so I fear this is yet another bug that will never be closed  - https://npm.community/t/workaround-for-npm-ci-no-optional-which-still-installs-optional-dependencies/8154/5

Comment: Confirm: `npm ci --no-optional` doesn't work.  Maxime Gélinas removing `package-json.lock` doesn't make any sense with `npm ci`

Comment: @faiwer Just to be clear, it should work without deleting `package-json.lock`, but if it don't then delete it **only once**, regenerate it and try again. Also, test it in a project with no dependency packages (e.g. `ms`, `uuid`) and you will see it works. Sometimes an optional dependency is a nested dependency of another package.

Comment: Do you mean regenerate it without optional dependencies?

Comment: @faiwer No, `npm i` should do it.

Comment: I checked it out. I removed `package-lock.json`, ran `npm i` (it created a new `package-lock.json` file). Then when I ran `npm ci --no-optional` in the docker with these `package*.json` files my `optionalDependencies` weren't installed. So, you're right. It looks like it's NPM bug and to avoid it we need to make a refresh for `-lock` file sometimes. Thank you

Comment: @MaximeGélinas I don't suppose you happen to remember the issue number for this? The last time I looked I could only find closed/wontfix for this problem.
Turns out my workaround has been biting us badly.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this issue with CI workflow script and even "--no-optional" was not working

```
npm ci --no-optional
```

The above command only worked when I added the optional package as

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.3.2"
}
```

in the package.json file

Comment: Helpful in the long run if you also note the npm version.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, even with the --no-optional.

Answer (score 3):

I am using npm version `9.8.0`: the `--no-optional` flag is deprecated, you can use `--omit=optional` or `--include=optional`.

I added this to my *.npmrc* file (in the root folder of my project, which by the way is using npm workspaces)

```
omit=optional
```

Now, if I run `npm ci` (or `npm install`) in my project, it does not install optional dependencies by default.

To install optional dependencies pass the `--include=optional` flag, for instance

```bash
npm ci --include=optional
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to make `npm ci --no-optional` skip/ignore an optional pacakge, it's important to understand how `npm` intracts with package.json and pacakge-lock.json.

1. `npm install --no-optional` (is only effective if pacakge-lock.json doesn't exists otherwise it would ignore --no-optional)*
2. `npm ci --no-optional` is only effective if pakcage-lock.json was already created with `npm install --no-optional`**.

* This means if you want to make an already installed package an  optional, you can would have to

1. Add it `"optionalDependencies":` either manulally or through `npm install pacakge-name --save-optional`
2. Delete the pacakge-lock.json.
3. then run `rm -rf node_modules/`
4. Lastly run `npm install --no-optional`
5. Add this point `npm ci --no-optional` isn't suppose to install it.

** **TIP**: you could debug if a certian package is assigned as optional by running `npm ls package-name`

**Note**: This one the reason why its recommended to keep trak pacakge-lock.json with git repo of the project.

Comment: While this is potentially a good answer, you need to update your answer to use --omit=optional

Answer (score 1):

It's not a proper solution, rather an ugly one, but it helped me out. It looks like `npm ci --no-optional` doesn't work and probably never worked. But at the same time flag `--production` works. And if we afford mutating `package.json` (e.g. in a docker container) then...

So I wrote a simple script that:

- reads `package.json` content
- `Object.assign(cfg.dependencies, cfg.devDependencies)`
- `delete cfg.devDependencies`
- overwrites the initial `package.json`

So finally we have:

- `dependencies` contains both normal & dev dependencies
- `devDependencies` section is empty
- `optionalDependencies` are intact

And when we run `npm ci --production` we got what we want - no optional dependencies (in my case `cypress`). Due to the fact that all these steps are performed inside of a docker container we can mutate `package.json`.

But I'm not sure that it'll help you too.