# What is ngrok-stable-windows-amd64

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, ngrok, popper.js

While installing `popper.js` using `npm i --save popper`, it started installing other packages rather than popper.js as you can see in the picture below. Why is it downloading **ngrok-stable-windows-amd64** which I have encircled in red in the picture.
[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqS8v.png)

Comment: Are you asking because you know what `ngrok` is but you don't understand why `popper.js` depends on it - or are you asking because you don't know what `ngrok` is in the first place?

Comment: I don't know any of two questions you asked above. Can you please tell a little bit about it. It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ngrok is an [optional dependency of popper](https://github.com/pemrouz/popper/blob/master/package.json#L33), used for tunneling.

You can skip its installation by [using `--no-optional` when you run NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59956230/362536).

Comment: Should I install popper.js as `npm i popper --save` or `npm i popper.js --save`?

Comment: @AchalKumarRai I wouldn't know... I don't know if you're trying to install `popper`, or `popper.js`.  They're two different packages, and you've mentioned both in your question.  Install whichever one you want to use.

Comment: What's the difference between popper and popper.js? I thought they are the same.